# Using Hive UDF's in Pig

Tags: hive, apache-pig, udf

Is there any reason not use Hive UDF's in Pig 0.15?

I'm thinking mostly about performance, but if there are any other reasons I'd be happy to hear them.

For example, we have a simple Java implementation of lpad that we use. Should we bother keeping it, or can we use the Hive version?

Answer (score 0):

Hive UDFs are supported in pig 0.15 version. See below.
http://hortonworks.com/blog/announcing-apache-pig-0-15-0/

Comment: That link doesn't answer my question. However, in the meantime, [PIG-4672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4672) was opened, which, when solved, will.